# Cmake support in Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, cmake

According to [this](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/doc/editors/Eclipse-UNIX-Tutorial), I have 3 options to use cmake in Eclipse CDT for C++. None of them works.

The first is because I use out-of-source builds and the limitations of the generator is so lame. Also, it uses a hardcoded Eclipse project template, so it is fragile like hell. The second is the poor man's version of cmake support. It does not add any value to Eclipse, really. The third one simply does not work. I can't make an existing cmake project. I can create a new one, but not opening an existing one. Also, the cmake properties in the project properties windows throw an exception and that's it. Does not even show up.

Is there any GOOD support in Eclipse for cmake? Or any other powerful IDE? Like adding the CmakeList.txt and the corresponding project is created? I am mainly interested in having the proper include paths and the global make targets based on the cmake files. And of course it would be nice to have syntax colored editing of cmake files, etc.

Comment: CMake support provided Yocto Eclipse plugin is good enough. Unfortunately, it is strongly linked with Yocto project. Volunteers would be welcomes to fork it.

Comment: You can also check https://github.com/15knots/cmake4eclipse (but I prefer cmake support provided by Yocto)

Comment: Visual Studio Code (Linux/windows/mac) plus appropriate extensions works exceptionally well

Answer (score 9):

We successfully use both Eclipse CDT and Qt Creator with a large CMake based project.

For Eclipse, we usually use option two exactly as described. There is also a CMake Eclipse plug-in called [CMake Editor](http://cmakeed.sourceforge.net/) for syntax highlighting and command completion.

Personally, I am using QtCreator. It has quite good CMake support and is very fast. You should initially configure your project with the CMake GUI (using the Make or NMake Generator) and then open your top-level CMakeLists.txt file in QtCreator and point it to your already configured binary directory.

Comment: No need for preconfiguration outside Qt Creator. It's support for CMake projects has improved greatly and it's very slick. I would go with Qt Creator for C++ before Eclipse CDT any time. Much better.

Answer (score 5):

Have you taken a look at [Qt Creator](http://qt.nokia.com/products/developer-tools/)? It might have the features you are looking for.

Comment: I believe it has support for cmake projects. Although off-late I think there has been a move toward qmake over cmake.

Comment: @Alessandro Pezzato qt creator is not only for QT Projects, it can be conveniently used with plain old C++ as well :-)

Comment: And with c it works almost perfectly too, just some parsing issues and hilghlighting c++ reserved words as errors, but QtCreator rocks, it's way more lightweight than eclipse.

Answer (score 5):

I use CMake GUI for generating CDT project or Unix makefiles and then import it via Eclipse.

Also I use KDevelop 4 because it simply opens CMake projects and tightly integrates CMake support.

Answer (score 3):

Congratulations, CLion http://www.jetbrains.com/clion/ new C++ IDE with CMake well integrated. See its features https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=MY_Z90Tj6is

Comment: Also [CMake simple highlighter](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10089-cmake-simple-highlighter) and [CMake Plus](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12869-cmake-plus) plugins may help with extra highlighting, navigation and code-completion support.

Answer (score 2):

I tried all three and have found option 2 to be the only useful one.  Option 1, the cmake CDT generator, is useless.  I cannot get option 3 to work either.

Yes, option 2 is the "poor man's version" insofar as you must follow a series of steps when setting up a new project, rather than pressing a single button.  But I have had good success with it for many projects in the past year.  Like you, I always do out of source builds.

Also, to get syntax coloring of CMake files, use the excellent [CMakeEd](http://www.cthing.com/CMakeEd.asp) plugin for eclipse.  It's beautiful.

Answer (score 2):

CDT has official CMake support plugin currently. You can find through Help->Install menu of Eclipse.

Comment: This menu does not exist anymore. Is it "Install New Software..." instead ? If yes, I was able to install "C/C++ Cmake Build Support - Preview" from Eclipse. But I was never able to open an existing CMake project, or import anything from an existing project into a newly created Eclipse project.