# C/C++ Qt CMake Ninja project in Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, qt, cmake, ninja

I have a project with the following characteristics :

- OS : Windows 10
- Language : C & C++ (both)
- Uses the Qt framework (including UI files and everything) (Qt 5.12.11)
- Configured with CMake (3.20.6)
- Uses Ninja as generator (1.10.2)

Until now I was using Qt Creator to work on it.

Can I open it, build it, run it, debug it - basically work on it with Eclipse ? If yes, how ?

None of the answers provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6915876/cmake-support-in-eclipse) are

- More recent than 2017 (question dates from 2011, most answers are from 2011 or 2012)
- Helpful.

The question itself mentions three options, two of which (1 and 3) refer to content that doesn't exist anymore, AFAICT. The middle option seems favored by one responder, but using Unix, and agreeing it's not ideal 8actually uses CMake GUI on the side).

One answer (the most recent, from 2017) mentions some further DLC which I think I did get (even though it is not actually named) but which I cannot figure out how to use.

The other answers suggest using other editors, which is irrelevant to my question (I am asking about Eclipse specifically).

Comment: Your edit is pretty rude, considering that a) you did not do your homework before asking your question and b) you dismiss everything in the listed dup as "not helpful" **without explaining why**. If you want a second opinion at least explain what is wrong with the options listed so people can help you find what you want.

Comment: Sorry, I absolutely don't mean it that way. I will explain more then. I have commented in the question that is supposed to be a duplicate of mine. I will explain some more here.

Comment: Hope it's better now.

Comment: Eclipse CDT seems to just have native CMake support nowadays, although I cannot find any conclusive documentation on it.

Comment: Exactly where I'm at.

Comment: So .. did you try it ? :)

Comment: See my comment on that answer in the duplicate question : yes, and I can't get it to work, as you say ... no clear doc anywhere ? I think I'm going to stick with Qt Creator for now. After all, it is sort of the native IDE for this.